# ASP.NET button onclick not reaching code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, onclick

My asp button control for some reason is not hitting my code behind. Any idea why?

HTML:

```
<td class="auto-style2">
    <asp:Button ID="btnEmailSelectedTotal" 
        runat="server" 
        Enabled="true" 
        Text="Email Selected Members" 
        OnClick="btnEmailSelectedTotal_Click"/>                                               
</td>
```

Code behind:

```
   protected void btnEmailSelectedTotal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "myalert", 
            "alert('" + "Got here" + "');", true);
        //build our cust GUID list based off each row that was checked by pulling
        //the hidden data from HiddenField_CustGUID for the corresponding checked row
        var lstCustGuid = new List<string>();
        var isEmailAll = true;

        PopulateCookieValues((int)Cookie.HeaderTotal);

        //first get the check box list. If we find a list item that is 
        //un-checked, assume this is not an email all
        foreach (GridViewRow rw in GridView_TotalCounts.Rows)
        {
            var chkBx = (CheckBox)rw.FindControl("EmailCheckbox");
            if (chkBx != null && chkBx.Checked)
            {
            lstCustGuid.Add(((HiddenField)rw.FindControl("HiddenField_CustGUID")).Value);
            }
            else if (chkBx != null && !chkBx.Checked)
            {
                //this is not email all. we discovered an un-checked checkbox.
                isEmailAll = false;
            }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Cookies.Header.Total) &&
            Cookies.Header.Total == "true" && isEmailAll)
        {
            //header is checked - this is email all
            //populate it with the full email guid list from the hidden field:
            lstCustGuid = HF_Total_FullEmailList.Value.Split(',').ToList();
        }

        NavigateToSendEmail(lstCustGuid);
    }
```

As you can see above, my first item I hit is a message box alert. Not even that is getting invoked. Any idea why the `onclick` is totally ignoring my code behind? What can i try to correct this?

I tried this across 2 different browsers and also cleared cache; didnt help.

Many thanks for the help!

Comment: Try recreating the event handler. Cut your code, delete the click handler, double-click the button to recreate the handler then paste your code back in. Sometimes they get disconnected. You can also simplify the js: `"alert('Got here');"` but I don't think that's the problem. Edit: is this button in a GridView? You might need to look up how to attach js/events to buttons in a gridview.

Comment: this isnt a dynamically created control right?

Comment: Is autoeventwireup property in aspx page is set to true? Also make sure it is not in any container with visible = false;